# Can we send Automated Reply to comments on fan page or public post on Facebook?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to send automated reply to comments or posts on the My product Facebook fan page  ? Also can do the same to all Facebook public post where people are discussing about product .

Comment: Check : [autorelaxed](http://autorelaxed.com/)